# When i close complete browser or when i close my applications last tab then only my applications session get cleared

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

```
<pre>
```

> When i close **complete browser**  or when i close **my applications last
>
>    tab** then only my applications session get cleared.

Comment: _"When i close complete browser"_.. You have a browser to test it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Session is cleared when **browser** closed.